# DNS - Use two wildcards on different domain levels

Tags: domain-name-system, wildcard-subdomain, wildcards

I have a problem with this DNS configuration:

```
RecordType - Name              - Value
A            *.domain.com        1.1.1.1
A            *.sub.domain.com    2.2.2.2
```

I would like all subdomains of `* .sub.domain.com` to point to `2.2.2.2` and everything else to point to `1.1.1.1`.

But i if I check `test.sub.domain.com` both records are active. That's not good.

```
opcode QUERY
rcode NOERROR
flags QR RD RA
;QUESTION
test.sub.domain.com. IN A
;ANSWER
test.sub.domain.com. 3599 IN A 1.1.1.1
test.sub.domain.com. 3599 IN A 2.2.2.2
;AUTHORITY
;ADDITIONAL
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: That sounds unexpected... what software is this?

Comment: I used [Google dig](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/) , [dnschecker](https://dnschecker.org/) and "dig" command. The result is the same for everyone..

Comment: Sorry, I was more looking for "what produced these answers"? Seems weird, assuming that the question does not misrepresent the zone data.

Comment: I opened a ticket on MisterDomain (our provider). I tried the same configuration on Gandi.net and all works fine.. I will add here other info if something happens. Thx

Comment: "Any idea how to do it?" Provide the real names involved for people to double check. Otherwise there could be a lot of idle speculation and wrong directions.

Comment: Perhaps also provide your DNS hosting provider. The exact setup to get this working will probably depend on which provider you are using.

Answer (score 2):

I'd wager this is some caching issue, as the more specific wildcard should always be the "winning" one. Check using `dig @server` directly from your name servers and see if you still get that response. If so, you have probably found a bug in your DNS provider's DNS software.